# Material-ui Autocomplete warning The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid. You can use the getOptionSelected` prop to customize the equality test

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete

I am working with Autocomplete material-ui. But I am getting a "The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid" warning.
None of the options match with `` "" `. You can use the` getOptionSelected` prop to customize the equality test"

```
<Autocomplete
  id="district combo-box-demo"
  value={defaultValueDistrict}
  onChange={(event, value) => {
    if (value && value.districtName) {
      setDefaultValueDistrict(value);
    }
  }}
  options={lisdata}
  getOptionLabel={(option) =>
    option.districtName ? option.districtName : ""
  }
  getOptionSelected={(option, value) =>
    option.districtName === value.districtName
  }
  style={{ width: 190 }}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <CssTextField
      style={{ background: "white" }}
      {...params}
      variant="outlined"
      placeholder="Nhập quận/huyện"
      name="district"
      onBlur={handleBlur}
    />
  )}
/>
```

I tried to follow the instructions but still failed. Everyone please help me

Comment: Ciao, how `lisdata` looks like? Can you show me?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito, I thank you for your interest in my problem. lisdata was calledapi, it was quite complicated, I created it basically from this link in the lisdata.js file:https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-bhabha-o345c?file=/src/lisdata.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, I made a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-autocomplete-forked-utqty?file=/src/App.js).

Basically I copied you code by adding:

1. imported data you passed me:

   ```
   import { lisdata } from "./lisdata";
   ```
2. added `defaultValueDistrict` state (with empty string as inital value)

   ```
   const [defaultValueDistrict, setDefaultValueDistrict] = useState("");
   ```
3. simulated data comes from an apicall:

   ```
   const [data, setData] = useState([]);

   const firstLoad = useRef(true);
   useEffect(() => {
    if (firstLoad.current) {  // this is just a technique to run below code just one time
      setTimeout(() => { // simulated called api (data comes after 5 sec)
        setData(lisdata);
      }, 5000);
      firstLoad.current = false;
    }
   });
   ```

Nothing more. I got no error in console.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, you are great. Have a nice day. thank you

Comment: No problem @TuânPhạm. Have a nice day you too

Comment: oh no, sorry but I still see the console.log warning in your demo when I select an item, can you check it for me?

Warning: React does not recognize the `getOptionSelected` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `getoptionselected` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

Comment: @TuânPhạm Yes I saw (but sometimes appears, sometimes no...) I'm investigating on it...

Comment: @TuânPhạm there is a bug on MUI library (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18443). The developer said that is solved on latest version... Anyway we can solve this warning by made couple of modifications: `defaultValueDistrict` default value should be `null`; `getOptionLabel` should returns something like `option.districtName ? option.districtName : null`; `getOptionSelected` should return `false` in case `value === null`. I updated my codesandboxexample and now there are no warnings in console. Let me know if you got other warnings :)

Comment: Ok, it works completely fine with no warning. You are fantastic. Once again I would like to thank you very much!

Comment: No problem @ TuânPhạm I learned something new solving this problem so thanks to you too :)